# Meta tag doesn't work on refreshing page (F5)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic, w3c

I am using meta tag to redirect user to our career page after 5 seconds in asp classic page.

Page works fine the first time you visit but if i refresh this page or press F5 then system won't redirect me to the specific page (IE).

I have used a meta tage on following two formats but still seeing same results.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=/careers/opportunities.asp" />`

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.mycompany.com/careers/opportunities.asp" />`

Both meta tags work fine on firefox.

Any fix for IE?

Comment: How about redirecting with javascript?

Comment: Edited your question for you so the meta tags would show. On stackoverflow, HTML tags that aren't marked as code get suppressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the page also and it should do the trick.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   x = setTimeout("window.location='whereever.asp';",5000);  //5000 = 5 seconds
 </script>
```

This is Javascript, which means it runs on the client, and gives a 5 second pause.

If you want to do a hard redirect on the server without giving any kind of notice like `You are being redirected`, then you can use `Response.Redirect`

```
 Response.Redirect("/whereever.asp")
```

Or

```
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","/whereever.asp"
```

Since Response.Redirect gives another Status code to the search engine, if SEO is not required, then any of these methods would work.

Comment: why php? my page is in asp classic?

Comment: instead of 'whereever.php' can i define the current page name?

Comment: yes of course, i was just going off the top example, any url can go there, you can see more information by googling `window.location` ;)